# Не работает через порт 8000

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

После того, как сделал сайт в pycharm, создал файл html и внес туда все необходимое я не могу зайти на сайт когда ввожу адрес localhost:8000, могу зайти только через иконки, которые отображаются в pycharm и после того, как перехожу на сайт через эти иконки, в адресной строке пишет совсем другой порт 63342, но в внизу т.е. в терминале пишет, что подключен через порт 8000. Что тут можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит вам о том, что Django не находит шаблон. Проверьте, что в директории `blog\templates\blog` находится файл `blog_list.html`.

---

Через "иконки" вы не заходите на сайт. Вы лишь открываете отдельные страницы с HTML кодом в браузере. Аналогично открытию любых других файлов через протокол `file://`

Comment: Все, получилось.) У меня в папке templates, еще одна папка была, надо было ее вписать в файле views.py.